# Angular's Deep linking - Dynamic Links vs Static Links

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

for a more decoupled modular approach, I've route handling outside in another ng-module.

the hash links generated by a controller (data binding) inside a separate ng-module are not triggering the route handler (in the first module) except statically generated links.

Question is how can you enable trigger handling for both kind of links.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ea1OHa?p=preview

Dynamic links

```
<div id="navigation" data-ng-cloak>
    <ul id="folios" data-ng-controller="FoliosController" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li data-ng-repeat="folio in folios" ng-class="{active: isActive('/search/{{folio.productId}}')}">
            <a href="#/search/{{folio.productId}}" >{{folio.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div ui-view>view</div>
</div>
```

Static Links:

```
<ul id="folios">
  <li><a href="#/search/foo">foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/search/bar">bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by using target="_self" for the dynamically generated links to trigger routing, for some reason the angular suppresses the links.